# UpdatePanel, Timer and TexBox Problem

Tags: asp.net, ajax, timer, updatepanel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" >
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="300" ontick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
<ContentTemplate>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Send" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Problem is that `TextBox1’s` cursor is not blinking it is static but you can write in it. It gives the impression that it freezed. Why cursor is not blinking?

Comment: Switching the focus might fix this. Did you try to use JavaScript to `TextBox1.blur()` and then `TextBox1.focus()`?

Comment: I'll post as an answer although I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: You try it - you already have all the code necessary. ;-)

Comment: Thanks this post helped me..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set  your  timer interval near as 1000 milliseconds. That should solve your blinking problem.

Answer (score 0):

When the post-back completes you can run a piece of JavaScript which will remove the focus from the textbox (e.g. it will no longer accept text) and then you can immediately re-focus on the textbox (so it will accept text again). This may "reset" the cursor so that it displays properly.

Try adding this to your ASPX, preferably outside of the UpdatePanels:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fixTextBoxFocus()
    {
        var textBox = document.getElementById("<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>");

        textBox.blur(); //Remove the focus from the text box.
        textBox.focus();//Re-focus on the textbox.
    }
</script>
```

And then, in your code-behind (replace `MyPage` with the name of your page's class):

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(MyPage), "fixTextBoxFocus", "fixTextBoxFocus();", true);
}
```

Now, when the partial-post-back occurs, this script will be executed each time. Give it a try and let me know if it helps to fix the issue.

Comment: Sorry it did not worked. Cursor is still static it is not blinking. I think it is due to `Timer`.

Answer (score 0):

Placing a timer inside an updatepanel will result in a repeat refresh of that update panel. SInce you have placed the timer interval as 300 milliseconds. That may be the problem.
What you need to think about -
Do you really want to place the timer in the update panel?
Do you really need to keep the interval as 300 milli seconds.
Will it not be possible to move the textbox outside the updatepanel?

Comment: I have placed `Timer` in other `UpdatePanel` not in the `TextBox` `UpdatePanel`. So `Timer`'s refresh should not disturb `TextBox`.